# Yielding when taking partial sums

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to find sublists of a set of probabilities, such that the sum of the negative binary logarithm of the sub list is 1 (or just past 1.0). Just finding the first such sublist would be fine.

To do this I thought I could use `takewhile` and generator expressions, yet I can't seem to get things working.

So far I have:

```
from itertools import takewhile
from numpy.random import dirichlet
from math import log

def partial_sums(iterable):
    total = 0
    for i in iterable:
        total += -1*log(i,2)
        yield total

probs = dirichlet([1]*1000).tolist()
probs = 10*probs
ps = partial_sums(probabilities)
s = takewhile(lambda x: x<1, sum(x for x in partial_sums(probs)))
```

This is just giving me an empty list however.

EDIT: If I was using Python 3. I could use itertools.accumulate:

```
s = takewhile(lambda x: x<1, itertools.accumulate(math.log(x,2) for x in probs))
```

I'm looking for a Python 2.7 equivalent.

EDIT: I thought that this:

```
def partial_sums(iterable):
    total = 0
    for i in iterable:
        total += -1*log(i,2)
        if total >= 1.0:
            yield i
```

would work, but alas it doesn't.

Comment: You are running `sum()`, which returns *one value*. That's not an iterable for `takewhile()` to loop over, and would result in an error instead. Where does `sum()` come from if it is not the built-in?

Comment: Also, did you mean to use `partial_sums(probs)` instead of `partial_sums(probabilities)`?

Comment: Your **first** value is already over 1; `next(ps)` returns `12.091043076201494`.

Comment: Your `takewhile()` sample is giving me a syntax error (`lambda` is misspelled) and you use `partial_sum` in it, without defining it. Can you please update your question to give us a *workable* piece of code?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, I'm having a bad day for mistyping. I basically just want to find the first sublist who's partial sum of logarithms is close to 1, then the second etc - I only want to do partial sums on a portion of the list, not the whole.

Comment: The documentation for `itertools.accumate()` includes a Python version that works fine on Python 2.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks, have changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
from itertools import takewhile
from numpy.random import dirichlet
from math import log

def partial_sums(iterable):
    total = 0
    for i in iterable:
        total += i
        yield total

probs = dirichlet([1]*1000).tolist()
probs = 10*probs
s = takewhile(lambda x: x<1, partial_sums(-1*log(x,2) for x in probs))
```

EDIT: As pointed out by Martijn Pieters, the documentation for itertools.accumulate contains the following function which works fine for Python 2:

```
def accumulate(iterable, func=operator.add):
    'Return running totals'
    # accumulate([1,2,3,4,5]) --> 1 3 6 10 15
    # accumulate([1,2,3,4,5], operator.mul) --> 1 2 6 24 120
    it = iter(iterable)
    total = next(it)
    yield total
    for element in it:
        total = func(total, element)
        yield total
```

This should be used in place of partial_sums() in the solution above.